# A managed resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw_id" has not been declared in module.eip

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying create eip and natgateway using terraform but i'm facing follwing error.

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on ../../modules/eip/main.tf line 7, in resource "aws_eip" "nat-gateway":
   7:   depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.igw_id]

A managed resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw_id" has not been declared in
module.eip.
```

Here is my main.tf

```
variable "igw_id" {}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat-gateway" {
  allocation_id = "*********"
  subnet_id     = "*********"
  depends_on    = [aws_internet_gateway.igw_id]

  tags {
    Name        = "*********"
    Service     = "*********"
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Here is my igw.tf

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = "********"
  tags = {
    Name        = "*********"
    Service     = "*********"
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}
```

output.tf

```
output igw_id {
  value = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
}
```

Comment: Well, have you actually craeted `aws_internet_gateway`? Your code does not show it.

Comment: yes I created it. I will add to the code. Just a moment.

Comment: I added some code. :)

Comment: Does your `module/eip/` directory contain both `main.tf` with the NAT gateway and `igw.tf` with the internet gateway? I'm finding it hard to follow how your code is structured from your question. Could you possibly edit the question so that you include the structure of your code (such as the output of `tree` or a version of that) and all of the required code to form a [mcve] please?

Comment: Yup, as @ydaetskcoR mentioned, the error is *not* related to the part of code you posted, but actually to the aws_eip resource, which you haven't posted here.

Comment: If your code examples here exactly match what you're trying to run, I notice that the error message is talking about a resource called `aws_internet_gateway.igw_id` but the resource configuration you shared is called just `aws_internet_gateway.igw` (no `_id` suffix). Removing the `_id` suffix from the `depends_on` may be enough to make this work.